# WordPress PHP Extended Classes Refer to 'Wrong' Static Variables

Tags: php, wordpress, static, extends

I have a WordPress plugin with 2 extended classes, Area and Loc, each of which has a helper function Get. Each class has static variables for table_name. If I call Loc::Get($id) directly, it works as expected. If, however, I call Loc::Get($id) from Area, it uses the table_name from Area rather than Location.

Can anyone explain how to correct this?  Regards,

```
class _Base {
    function Get($id) {
        $instance = new self();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . static::$table_name . " WHERE id=$id";
        return $sql;
    }
}

class Area extends _Base {
    static $table_name = "Area";
    function getLoc($id) {
        $sql = Loc::Get($id);
        return $sql;
    }
}

class Loc extends _Base {
    static $table_name = "Loc";
}
```

---

```
$sql = Area::Get(1); // -> "SELECT * FROM **Area** WHERE id=1"

$sql = Loc::Get(1); // -> "SELECT * FROM **Loc** WHERE id=1"

$sql = $area->GetLoc(1); // -> "SELECT * FROM **Area** WHERE id=1"
```

Comment: You want to read a bit about "late state binding" (sometimes also shorter called "late binding"). For the issue at hand: the behavior does make sense: Both derived classes define the same static variable. In the scope of `Area` the value is "Area" obviously. The method you call is executed in the scope of the `Area` class too, so that table name will be picked, since the function accesses the static variable defined in the current scope.

Comment: What you exactly want? Also what is your expected outcome, please tell both. thanks

Comment: @anantkumarsingh I'd say both your questions are clearly answered in the OPs question above... He expects table name "Loc" to be used, which is not the case.

Comment: As a solution you can either hand over the static variable as an additional argument to the `Get()` method, or you redefine the method in each class or you implement late state binding for that method.

Comment: Where did you declare your $table_name variable in your parent class Base?

Comment: Why you don't use a getter and setter, instead of using static? Is this a homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is you run NON static method `Get` as static. When i changed it then all start work fine. Try my code below:

```
<?php
class _Base {
    static function Get($id) {
        $instance = new self();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . static::$table_name . " WHERE id=$id";
        return $sql;
    }
}

class Area extends _Base {
    static $table_name = "Area";
    function getLoc($id) {
        return Loc::Get($id);
    }
}

class Loc extends _Base {
    static $table_name = "Loc";
}

var_dump(Area::Get(1));
var_dump(Loc::Get(1));
var_dump((new Area)->getLoc(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

First

Function Get is not static by definition
`function Get($id) {`

Second

`$area` is not defined